# JQuery dynamically added row, click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read several stackoverflow answers related to my problem saying that when you dynamically add a row, the best way to make to new row respond to events is to have a $('.class_name').on('click',function(e) {  declaration instead of $('.class_name').click(function() {

That made sense to me so I tried it and it still doesn't work.  Nothing happens when I click the inserted link in the inserted row.  I've put the code in a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/osctqotj/

Or pasted below.  Here is my HTML

```
<table>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="num_1" cnt="1" class="num-link">1</a></td><td>Harry</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="num_2" cnt="2" class="num-link">2</a></td><td>Sally</td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="num_3" cnt="3" class="num-link">3</a></td><td>Wally</td></tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id='add-row' value='Add Row'>
<br/><br/>
<input type='text' id='write-rank' curcnt='0' style='width: 15px;'>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
$('.num-link').on('click',function(e) { 
    var cnt = $(this).attr('cnt');
    $("#write-rank").attr('curcnt', cnt);
    var x = $(this).position();
    $("#write-rank").val('');
    $("#write-rank").css({top: x.top - 4, left: x.left - 5, position:'absolute'});  
    $("#write-rank").show();
    $("#write-rank").focus();
});

$('#add-row').on('click',function(e) { 
    add_row_for_new_user('Pablo');
});

function add_row_for_new_user(new_user_name) {
      var dis = $(".num-link:first");
      var $curRow = $(dis).closest('tr');
      $newRow = get_blank_row(new_user_name);
      $curRow.before($newRow);
    }

function get_blank_row(new_user_name) {
   var ret = '<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="num_99" cnt="99" class="num-link">0</a></td><td>'+new_user_name+'</td></tr>';
  return ret;     
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For reference: [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Its not `$('.class_name').on('click',function(e) {` it should be `$('parentSelector').on('click', '.class_name', function(e) {`. Also make sure that ID is not repeated when creating multiple dynamic elements

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to `document events` and compare the selectors.
NOT listen to selector's events.

Change the JS to:

```
$(document).on('click','.num-link', function(e) { 
    var cnt = $(this).attr('cnt');
    $("#write-rank").attr('curcnt', cnt);
    var x = $(this).position();
    $("#write-rank").val('');
    $("#write-rank").css({top: x.top - 4, left: x.left - 5, position:'absolute'});  
    $("#write-rank").show();
    $("#write-rank").focus();
});

$(document).on('click', '#add-row' ,function(e) { 
    add_row_for_new_user('Pablo');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation methods, for example

```
$('body').on('click', '#add-row',function(e) { 
    add_row_for_new_user('Pablo');
});
```